# ¿cómo agregar campos selects dependientes en el checkout de woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy desarrollando una tienda que ofrece días de entrega locales de acuerdo al código postal. He limitado los códigos postales con un select mediante este snippet

```
add_filter('woocommerce_default_address_fields' , 'custom_override_default_postcode_field');
function custom_override_default_postcode_field( $address_fields ) {
    // Códigos postales 
    $postcode_array = array(
            '28001' => '28001',
            '28002' => '28002',
            '28923' => '28923');
    $address_fields['postcode']['type'] = 'select';
    $address_fields['postcode']['options'] = $postcode_array;
    return $address_fields;
}
```

Estoy usando el plugin [woocommerce checkout field editor](https://woocommerce.com/es-es/products/woocommerce-checkout-field-editor/) donde agrego el campo "días de entrega", que es un select con los valores Lunes, martes, miercoles ...

Ahora quiero hacer que el segundo campo sea dependiente del primero, de acuerdo a las especificaciones de mi cliente, por ejemplo:

Código postal 28001 / Días de Entrega Lunes y miercoles

Código postal 28002 / Días de Entrega Martes y Jueves

Código postal 28923 / Días de Entrega Viernes y Domingo

Es decir, que cuando el comprador elija un código postal, sólo le muestre a elegir los días correspondientes.

Puedo prescindir del uso del plugin si existiese una forma de hacerlo todo mediante código.

Mil gracias por su ayuda,
Luis

Comment: Es mas sencillo utilizar el propio plugin de Woocomerce para realizar esta tarea, solo añádele atributos.

Comment: hola @winset según entiendo, los atributos están asociados al producto. Son como tallas, colores, etc. Lo que necesito está asociado al pedido en general (checkout). Necesito que el cliente pueda elegir una fecha de entrega y que esta dependa del código postal.

Comment: buenas tardes ¿Lograste alguna solución?

Comment: Hola, desafortunadamente no amigo. Ya no puedo recordar que solución le dimos al problema porque eso fue hace un tiempo atrás.